# Как реализовать систему лайкинга на постах и в дальнейшем обрабатывать их?

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Стоит такая задача - 
В API есть модель "Post". В ней есть пару полей из разряда "id", "price", "name", "description" и т.д. 
Необходимо реализовать систему лайкинга. То есть когда зарегистрированный пользователь на клиенте(в данном случае, мобильное приложение) нажимает на кнопочку лайка, срабатывал какой-то функционал лайкинга. Также необходимо, чтобы через API можно было достучаться к этим "лайкнутым" постам.
Не знаю как это можно реализовать, чтобы в дальнейшем не перелопачивать всю API, когда потребуется всё сделать по-человечески...

Пользователь стучится ко всем постам по такому URL - url.com/post/all
К конкретному, с большим кол-вом данных url.com/post/detail/1 - где "1" это ID поста

Есть ли какие-то примеры, best practices? Никак не могу найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Модель

Для начала Вам потребуется создать модель. Предлагаю использовать `ContentType`. Это позволит связывать наш лайк сразу с несколькими моделями, что очень удобно в свою очередь.

***models.py:***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Post(models.Model):
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

### API

Предлагаю сделать like методом для нашей модели. Но перед этим нам нужно подготовить несколько скриптов.

***services:***

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from core.models import Like
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def add_like(obj, user):
    obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    like, is_created = Like.objects.get_or_create(content_type=obj_type, object_id=obj.id, user=user)

    return like


def remove_like(obj, user):
    obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    Like.objects.filter(content_type=obj_type, object_id=obj.id, user=user).delete()


def is_fan(obj, user) -> bool:
    obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    likes = Like.objects.filter(content_type=obj_type, object_id=obj.id, user=user)

    return likes.exists()


def get_fans(obj):
    obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)

    return User.objects.filter(likes__content_type=obj_type, likes__object_id=obj.id)
```

***mixins:***

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from core.api import services
from core.api.serializers import FanSerializer


class LikedMixin:
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = self.get_object()
        services.add_like(obj, request.user)

        return Response()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def unlike(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = self.get_object()
        services.remove_like(obj, request.user)

        return Response()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def get_fans(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = self.get_object()
        fans = services.get_fans(obj)
        serializer = FanSerializer(fans, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

***serializers:***

```py
class FanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'full_name',
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_full_name(obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()
```

Не забудьте обновить поля в `serializers` также для модели Вашей записи и после этого можно приступать к финальной части.

### Представление

Наследуемся от недавно созданного mixin и радуемся!

***views.py:***

```py
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
```

Теперь у нас есть несколько новых API методов для нашей записи.

*Примечание: не забудьте, что метод like требует POST запроса, это может ввести Вас в заблуждение*
[image: Пример]

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за твой ответ :) Я проверю и отпишу в течение суток. Сейчас не могу, к сожалению.

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста - как мне использовать метод like/unlike/get_fans к посту? Как прописать url? Адрес до поста такой - example.com/api/v1/post/detail/5/

Comment: @TheGreatVY Я точно не уверен, как у Вас устроена маршрутизация, но попробуйте просто в конце дописать `/like`. Посмотреть точнее Вы можете в "browseable-API". django rest framework автоматически добавит эти действия и они будут доступны по кнопке "Extra Actions", там точно и посмотрите Ваш URL. Я добавил к ответу скриншот для наглядности.

Comment: Хм, у меня почему-то области Extra Actions нет. Не мог бы ты, пожалуйста, выложить исходники? Я был бы очень благодарен... :)

Comment: Извини, если предоставляю какие-то неудобства... Просто я новенький в django. Так пишу онли на Swift, C#...

Comment: @TheGreatVY Хорошо, до конца дня постараюсь компактно собрать всё и выложить :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду ждать :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! :)

Comment: привет! Тут появился один трабл. Связан с дальнейшей реализацией лайкинга, которое ты предложил) Посмотри, пожалуйста - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998404/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-filtering-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5