# Как использовать Filtering в данном случае?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Ранее задавал вопрос - [Как реализовать систему лайкинга на постах и в дальнейшем обрабатывать их?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994532/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%85)

Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо реализовать функционал фильтрации.
Использую для этого `django-filtering`.

views.py:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend


class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = ('isFan', )
```

Но как только я прописываю в `filterset_fields` ключ `isFan`, то появляется ошибка `'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: isFan`.

На сколько я понимаю, ключ isFan добавляется позже. Либо же я немного не понимаю жизненный цикл этих классов :)

Подскажите, пожалуйста - как реализовать систему поиска по этому ключу с таким функционалом?

Comment: Вы, наверное, плохо поняли, что это обозначает :) `isFan` - это `SerializerMethodField`. Добавляется в самом конце и означает, лайкнули ли Вы пост, который сейчас просматриваете или нет. Используется в большинстве случаев для того, чтобы подсвечивать иконку лайка. Это поле не привязано ни к какой модели со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: Исходя из моего комментария выше, невозможно реализовать фильтрацию по этому ключу, да и зачем? Считайте, что это поле - просто ответ на вопрос: _"Я лайкнул этот пост?"_.

Comment: Лучше задавать такие вопросы под соответствующими ответами. Это вопрос, привязанный к конкретной реализации.