# Полномочия для action (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!
Есть объект `Post`, для которого могут быть применены Actions. В моем случае, это система лайкинга определенного поста. Реализовывал ее по ответу в одном из моих вопросов -

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994532/Как-реализовать-систему-лайкинга-на-постах-и-в-дальнейшем-обрабатывать-их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994532/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85)

На ViewSet'е у меня стоит полномочие, что если author не является request.user, то мы не разрешаем `POST` запрос. Но как в итоге "ставить лайк другим"?

К примеру, вот URL - `posts/39/like`. Это считается `POST` запросом, но меня выкидывает на 403 ошибку -  `"detail": "У вас нет прав для выполнения этой операции."`

Как поставить отдельные права/полномочия для actions у объекта?

Answer (score 0):

Пришло в голову такое решение -
Так как это detail url для объекта Post, то тут по сути и негде делать POST запросы. Только если PUT или Delete.

Добавил в полномочия проверку на POST запрос - просто return True. А на PUT и Delete проверка является ли request.user == object.author.